# Writing to an S3 key based on current date

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, python-s3fs

I am trying to write a csv in S3 using `S3FileSystem` in python. Every time I write, I create a file with the current date-time ('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S') within a key of the current date ('%Y-%m-%d') so that the data is organized per date. I was thinking that this way, the data will be organized per date and no new key will be created for the same day.

```
file_name_s3 = f"{strftime('%Y-%m-%d', gmtime())}/test_feature-{strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S', gmtime())}.csv"
```

But looks like I am run. If I run the below code say on today's date (2021-03-17), first time this key `2021-03-17` is created. The next time it creates a new key `2021-03-18` even though I am running it on the same day.

Can anyone please suggest how to solve this?

Full code below

```
file_name_s3 = f"{strftime('%Y-%m-%d', gmtime())}/test_feature-{strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S', gmtime())}.csv"
writekey = 'rca/RnD/test/'+file_name_s3
bucket = 'mybucket'


def write_to_s3(bucket, writekey, result_feature_dict):
    '''
    Writes the feature dictionary as a CSV to S3
    '''
    print("Writing to S3...")
    s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False)
    toCSV = []
    for key, value in result_feature_dict.items():
        toCSV.append(value)
    keys = toCSV[0].keys()
    
    with s3.open('{}/{}'.format(bucket, writekey), mode='w', newline='') as f:
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, keys)
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        dict_writer.writerows(toCSV)
```

**Update**

This actually works. The date was in UTC so even though my local date was the same, the date changed in UTC which created confusion.

Comment: Can you reproduce this without all of the S3 interfacing stuff?

Comment: Is it the same day in UTC/GMT though? Are you expecting local date? My recommendation is to use UTC unless absolutely necessary

Comment: @teambob you are right. It writes in UTC date so even though the day was same in local time, it was changed wrt UTC